# Finding uncommon elements in Seq of Tuples

Tags: scala, tuples

I'm attempting to return a Seq of elements that are not common to each user :

```
val l1 = ("" , Seq( ("a" , 1) , ("b" , 2) , ("c" , 3) ) )
                                                  //> l1  : (String, Seq[(String, Int)]) = ("",List((a,1), (b,2), (c,3)))
val l2 = ("" , Seq( ("a" , 4) , ("d" , 5) , ("c" , 6) ) )
                                                  //> l2  : (String, Seq[(String, Int)]) = ("",List((a,4), (d,5), (c,6)))

val t1 = l1._2                                    //> t1  : Seq[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,2), (c,3))
val t2 = l2._2                                    //> t2  : Seq[(String, Int)] = List((a,4), (d,5), (c,6))
```

Intersecting the elements seems like an obvious method but an empty List is returned :

```
t1.intersect(t2)                                  //> res0: Seq[(String, Int)] = List()
```

should return `( ("b" , 2) , ("d" , 5) )` as these tuples are not common in l1 & l2

Can the intersect method be used in this or is there an alternative approach ?

Comment: What do `l1` and `l2` tuples have to do with your question? I see them only obfuscating your intent. Please narrow your questions down as much as possible before posting.

Comment: `intersect` will return what elements are common across the `Seq`s whereas `diff` will return what is different.  You would want `diff`, but it still will not satisfy your non-standard requirement for diffing.  The reason you are getting an empty `Seq` with `intersect` is that there are no common pairs of tuples between the two `Seq`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, using either `diff` or `intersect` probably won't help you solve your problem.  There might be something better built in, but if there is not, then you can use logic similar to this (which is in long form so that the different steps are clear):

```
val l1 = Seq( ("a" , 1) , ("b" , 2) , ("c" , 3) )
val l2 = Seq( ("a" , 4) , ("d" , 5) , ("c" , 6) )

val m1 = l1.toMap
val m2 = l2.toMap

val differentKeys = m1.keySet.diff(m2.keySet)  ++ m2.keySet.diff(m1.keySet)
val result = (l1 ++ l2).filter{
  case (k, v) => differentKeys.contains(k)
}
println(result)
```

Comment: Using the intermediate Maps and `filterKeys` this could be written slightly more concise: `(m1 ++ m2).filterKeys(differentKeys)`